# How to convert any letter into a dash (for hangman game)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm a very new beginner to learning python3. 
For an assignment, I am trying to learn how to convert all letters in a word into dashes without losing the original secret word, so I can use it to play hangman.

How would I convert the word happy to ----- ?

Please give the simplest answer as I am a very new beginner.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: You need 2 copies of the word. The original and the one with dashes. Ex: `word = "Hello"; dashes = "-" * len(word)`

Comment: I don’t know python but you can use string replace in most languages. A google search for “python string replace” gave me this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can you replace method of string for this. 
The `replace` methods does not mutate the original string.

```
test_string = '123123123'
result_string = test_string.replace('1', '-')

print(test_string) // 123123123
print(result_string) // -23-23-23
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
word = "Hello"
wordAsDash = ""
for letter in word:
    wordAsDash += "-"
```

Or

```
word = "Hello"
wordAsDash = "-" * len(word)
```

Or you do something similar to the following:

```
word = "Hello"
alpha = "abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyx"
wordAsDash = ""
for letter in word.lower():
    if letter in alpha:
        wordAsDash += "-" #replace letter with -
    elif letter == " ":
        wordAsDash += letter #in case it's a series of words
    else:
        pass #do something about potential apostrophes or symbols
```

There are many ways to approach this. The final solution is the only one accounting for symbols or more than one word, so consider this when you work out your own solutions.